# Change HTTP internal links to HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, seo, https

I recently changed my magento to use HTTPS for all secure and unsecure urls. The one thing I notice is that all my internal links are set to HTTP instead of HTTPS, which slows down the website since the requestes are getting redirect to HTTPS.

Any ideas on how to set the internal link to HTTPS

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you create or edit CMS pages or blocks, please make sure that you always use **directives** and don't include a complete URL.

This has the following advantages:

- **switching to SSL works without anything having to be edited**
- the links will always work, on staging, local, live, elsewhere

For links ( tags) you should do this:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='page.html'}}">page name</a>
```

This becomes e. g. https://www.yourdomain.com/page.html

For pictures ( tags) please do as follows:

```
<img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/products/pic.jpg'}}" alt="your description of picture" />
```

This becomes e. g. https://www.yourdomain.com/media/wysiwyg/products/pic.jpg

Comment: Definitely a good idea to use this structuring. Also helps in multistore when you have a CMS page available to all store views `<a href="{{store url="link-here"}}" >link text</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If all your links are relative then setting the unsecure and secure urls to https should work but if all your internal links are absolute, you have to go through and change them to https

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They are relative. I have not made any changes to magento original code.